# How to import a class in a controller of CakePHP 2.0?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am using CakePHP. I created an external class which is not a model nor a controller. The structure of the class looks like this

```
class UploadImage{
    function sayHello(){
       return "hahaha";
   }
}
```

I saved the class in the App->Lib directory and named it as UploadImage.php

I wanted to call the method `sayHello()` in my controller which is:

```
class ContentsController extends AppController {

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function index() {
        $test = App::uses('UploadImage','Lib');
        debug($test->sayHello());
    }
}
```

Now when I run the above page, I get the following error:

> Error: Call to a member function sayHello() on a non-object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

App::uses() is a statement you place at the beginning of the file

you still have to program in php5 - meaning that you have to use `new`!

```
App::uses('UploadImage','Lib');
class ContentsController extends AppController {}
```

and in your method:

```
$test = new UploadImage();
```

Comment: I tried but now it shows another error:  Class 'UploadImage' not found  when the class is in app->Lib folder

Comment: @madi I am having the same exact problem as you were. Based on this answer and also the manual, what is listed here should work. Any reason why it would not?

Comment: You should put it as the first line