# How to load Model in Cakephp directly

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.9

before testing all my models in Cakephp app using `./cake test app AllModel` I have to do some manipulations. I use Cakephp 2.9.7. This function is declared in `AllModelTest.php` which looks the next way:

```
class AllModelTest extends CakeTestSuite {
    public static function suite() {        
        $suite = new CakeTestSuite('All model tests');
        $suite->addTestDirectory(TESTS . 'Case/Model');
        return $suite;
    }
}
```

How can I access my Model and do some manipulations direct from this file ? I tried `App::uses('MyModel', 'Model');`  - that is not working. `$this` I can't use, because it gives me error `PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in path....`

Comment: can you try $this->loadModel('CakeTestSuite');

Comment: `$this->loadModel('Your Model Name');`

Comment: @AlivetoDie I cannot call `$this` becaus i get error `PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in path...`

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339680/how-to-import-a-class-in-a-controller-of-cakephp-2-0

Comment: This might be useful to you: http://andy-carter.com/blog/loading-cakephp-models-inside-other-models-and-controllers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ClassRegistry`

```
$yourModel = ClassRegistry::init('YourModelName');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use ClassRegistry

```
$var = ClassRegistry::init("ModelName");
```